# Replace character defined by ASCII code (by something else)

Tags: catcodes

I am trying to replace, in a given string, some characters. The characters to be replaced is given by its ASCII code. So for example, in `abc`, I want to replace character `97` (which is `a`, but I don't know this yet) by something else, let's say a dot (`.`).

Now, `a`, `\char97` and `\char\thenumber` all look the same to me when printing them in a document, but replacing this respective argument in a string `a` only works with the first. Why is that, and how can I solve it? This is my MWE (unchanged from the original question):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcounter{number}
\setcounter{number}{97}
\newcommand{\replace}[1]{\StrSubstitute{#1}{a}{.}}
\begin{document}
a

\char97

\char\thenumber

\replace{a}

\expandafter\replace{\char97}

\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\replace{\char\thenumber}

\end{document}
```

Comment: `\char97` is not the same as `a`: the former is three tokens, the latter just one. There are situations where `a` and `\char97` might result in very different output (math mode, in particular). The construction `\expandafter\replace\expandafter{\char97}` can't work (in yours `\expandafter` does nothing) because `\char` is not expandable.

Comment: BTW, `\char\value{number}` or `\symbol{\value{number}}` is much better than `\char\thenumber`, because `\thenumber` can expand into something that is not a number. And if it expands to a number, then it does not stop for looking digits in the following text.

Comment: Are you after ``\number`a``?

Comment: `\expandafter` does only expand the token after the next token, thus the example expands the unexpandable `{` three times in summary. And even if you insert `\expandafter` after `\replace`, `\char` is not expandable.

Comment: Aaaaalright, `\char` is not expandable. That's the information I was missing. No, `\number` is not was I was looking for: I wanted to use `\StrSubstitute`.

Comment: @bers why do you want to use \StrSubstitute? Joseph's comment answers your question as written (and is _far_ more efficient than using  string substitution macros)

Comment: @ David Carlisle: ``\number`a`` returns `97`, I do not see how this is helping. Yes, ``\char\number`a`` outputs `a`, but: 1. I want to replace to list of characters **given by ASCII codes** in a string (so I already have the result of `\number`), and 2. ``\replace{\char\number`a}`` does not work in my MWE either.

Comment: @bers replacing a by 97 is exactly replacing a character by its ascii code. If you don't want that perhaps you should edit to change the question as I can't guess what else you do want given the question title?

Comment: Oh, now I get it. The title is confusing, sorry! I meant to ask how to "Replace character **defined** by ASCII code (by something else)" ...

Comment: `\StrSubstitute{#1}{\char97}{.}`?

Comment: That's what's not working, see my MWE :)

Comment: @bers Since you have an answer you should post it (it's not bad style). However… I did not understand what you want; the sentence “replace a character given by its ASCII code” and the title don't look clear to me. What is what you mean by “given by its ASCII code”? So, apart from answering it, I think you should edit the question so it is more clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a standard `\lowercase` trick which creates a token with a given ASCII code. For example you need to replace all ASCII 97 characters from the string `abcabcac` by double `?`. Then you can try:

```
\bgroup\lccode`X=97 \lowercase{\egroup \StrSubstitute{abcabcabc}{X}{??}}
output:  ??bc??bc??bc
```

This code creates the token with given ASCII code instead the `X` letter and then the `\StrSubstitute` macro is executed.

Of course, your processed string cannot include the `X` letter itself. If this is a problem then you can create the following `\replace` macro:

```
\def\replace#1{\bgroup \lccode`X=#1 \lowercase{\egroup \replaceA{X}}{abcabcabcXuv}}
\def\replaceA#1#2{\StrSubstitute{#2}{#1}{??}}

\replace{97}
output:  ??bc??bc??bcXuv
\replace{98}
output:  a??ca??ca??cXuv
```

Comment: Perhaps use `^^@` to avoid a char likely to be in the input?

Comment: @JosephWright I don't know `\StrSubstitute` but may be it expects exactly ASCII+category. It means that you need to say ``\catcode`^^@=11`` before using it, because the `a`, `b` characters are letters. Or you need to convert the processed string to tokens of catcode 12 (by `\meaning` primitive, for example).

Comment: I was thinking something like ``\begingroup\catcode`\^^@=11\relax\gdef\replace#1{\bgroup...``so that the catcode would be 'right'. Of course, that can't cover the case of different chars with different catcodes, but it's not clear to me what is wanted in that respect from the question.

Comment: Not having tried it, but this looks very much like what I wanted (without having to use LuaTeX or expl3 or ...).

Answer (score 4):

The TeX `\char` primitive is not expandable. This means that in the example the attempted expansion

```
\expandafter\replace\expandafter{\char97}
```

does nothing and is equivalent to

```
\replace{\char97}
```

which for hopefully-obvious reasons fails to match a literal `a`. What is needed is therefore some expandable way to turn a number into a char. Classical TeX offers us the `\ifcase` primitive, which is used in the general form

```
\ifcase<number> %
   <case 0>\or
   <case 1>\or
   <case 2>\or
   ...
   <case n>\else
   <no match>
\fi
```

Thus with appropriate set up it's possible to do a case-by-case conversion. Such an approach is taken by LaTeX's `\@alph` and `\@Alph`, which index lower-/upper-case letters, respectively, from 1:

```
\@alph{1}% => a
```

Clearly here some maths made  be needed to get the offset right. Such an approach is expandable but is obviously tedious for long lists of chars.

It's possible to set up a 'selective' case statement that is expandable: there is one pre-built in for example [`expl3`](http://ctan.org/pkg/expl3)

```
\int_case:nnF { <number> }
  {
    {  97 } { a }
    { 101 } { e }
    { 105 } { i }
    { 111 } { o }
    { 117 } { u }
  }
  { No~match }
```

There is a performance hit over the primitive for short lists of continuous integer ranges but better input format and clarity, particularly for long lists. (I think there are other implementations of the same concept in addition to the `expl3` one.)

The problem with any case-by-case approach is if you are looking beyond ASCII to the entire UTF-8 range. If LuaTeX is in use then there *is* an expandable primitive that will do the job

```
\Uchar97 % => a
```

That's obviously the easiest solution if you can be sure of the engine in use.

Answer (score 0):

What I wanted to achieve I achieved using `\@Alph` and `\@alph`, since my input ASCII codes are in the a-z, A-Z range. `\@Alph` etc. appear to expand to the 'real' letters. As multiple others have pointed out, `\char` is not expandable. I hope this may help someone else sometime.