# How creating a style or typeset for my own symbol

Tags: fonts, typography, hyphenation, scripts

I write my own symbol or language script.
How defining in TeX or Latex this symbol in new alphabet?

source code

```
This is example of my word: VVielka z1ool2ta z1aba z1arl2a z1ur.
```

efect

```
This is example of my word: Wielka żółta żaba żarła żur.
```

My symbol is always a one char+one letter or number.
VV=W=0x0057 i need hyphenation too. {VVie-lka}
Is any tutorial to create my own way to convert chars to symbol? I have my own font in fontforge format.
I need only convert from tex source 2 chars: VV into one W char (seting utf8 number to this char) and not lost hyphenation and other information like ad \bf \tt etc.
Meybe i must create a style?

Comment: Typically one uses a macro.  See the Comprehensive Symbol List from CTAN.

Comment: any tutorial or small example? i search any way to write my own Type­set­ting but where is working example. Please vote this question

Comment: `\chardef\VV="0057` will cause `\VV` to be replaced by `W`, and `\def\W{VV}` will cause `\W` to be replaced by `VV`.

Comment: @JohnKormylo sory this not answer. I ask normal text and style to read normal text similar new language not \def

Comment: It would be easier to use `change all` with an editor.  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/195726/replace-character-defined-by-ascii-code-by-something-else and the xstring package.

Comment: @JohnKormylo this is not answer. better way is not using tex ;-(

Comment: To change W to VV or VV to W, absolutely!  But if you want to do equations...

Comment: @JohnKormylo not funny